# How to create Image Object in react-native?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I want to create one pulse Splash wave App loading screen using a react-native-pulse library I am able to create Pulse screen but when I am trying to add thumbnail image inside it I have to pass Image object as a parameter but not able to create Image object using the new keyword. Can anyone have any idea how to create Image object or how to invoke Image constructor?

I tried the following things 
React Native Pulse: "https://github.com/sahlhoff/react-native-pulse"

Image Obj: "https://gist.github.com/danieljharvey/0d0e36333f31c405f3011833f357dddd"

Comment: Post the code that you are working on and which error you are experiencing.

Comment: Actually, the code is present in the first link I referred that only and for Pulse tag, I was trying to pass Image but the parameter is of image type so I tried to refer the second link to create Image object but got no luck